# Excel VBA - Reference a string for Worksheets command

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet, named "EDR".  On this sheet I have many activeX controls (command buttons, checkboxes, comboboxes, etc.).  The activeX controls misbehave and will move around or change size when clicked.  As a result, I use a brute force approach and resize/relocate the buttons whenever they are clicked.

I use the same steps for every button, but have to reference a different cell, which is where the buttons is located.  A portion of my code is as follows:

```
    If ButtonType = "cmdJSON" Then
        cell = "N13:O13"
        Worksheets("EDR").cmdJSON.AutoSize = False
        Worksheets("EDR").cmdJSON.AutoSize = True
        Worksheets("EDR").cmdJSON.Height = Worksheets("EDR").Range(cell).Height * 1.5
        Worksheets("EDR").cmdJSON.Left = Worksheets("EDR").Range(cell).Left
        Worksheets("EDR").cmdJSON.Top = Worksheets("EDR").Range(cell).Top + Worksheets("EDR").Range(cell).Height / 4
        Worksheets("EDR").cmdJSON.Width = Worksheets("EDR").Range(cell).Width
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If ButtonType = "cmdGraph" Then
        cell = "Z19:AA19"
        Worksheets("EDR").cmdGraph.AutoSize = False
        Worksheets("EDR").cmdGraph.AutoSize = True
        Worksheets("EDR").cmdGraph.Height = Worksheets("EDR").Range(cell).Height * 1.5
        Worksheets("EDR").cmdGraph.Left = Worksheets("EDR").Range(cell).Left
        Worksheets("EDR").cmdGraph.Top = Worksheets("EDR").Range(cell).Top + Worksheets("EDR").Range(cell).Height / 4
        Worksheets("EDR").cmdGraph.Width = Worksheets("EDR").Range(cell).Width
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If ButtonType = "cmdCopyCO2" Then
        cell = "AH15"
        Worksheets("EDR").cmdCopyCO2.AutoSize = False
        Worksheets("EDR").cmdCopyCO2.AutoSize = True
        Worksheets("EDR").cmdCopyCO2.Height = Worksheets("EDR").Range(cell).Height
        Worksheets("EDR").cmdCopyCO2.Left = Worksheets("EDR").Range(cell).Left
        Worksheets("EDR").cmdCopyCO2.Top = Worksheets("EDR").Range(cell).Top
        Worksheets("EDR").cmdCopyCO2.Width = Worksheets("EDR").Range(cell).Width
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

This works, but I could clean things up a lot if I could just use the ButtonType text in my worksheets commands.  Then I could simply have the same six lines for every button and just use a select case for the cell location.

Something like this:

```
Select Case ButtonType
   Case "cmdJSON" 
       cell = "N13:O13"
   Case "cmdGraph"
       cell = "Z19:AA19"
   Case "cmdCopyCO2" 
       cell = "AH15"
End Select

Worksheets("EDR").ButtonType.AutoSize = False
Worksheets("EDR").ButtonType.AutoSize = True
Worksheets("EDR").ButtonType.Height = Worksheets("EDR").Range(cell).Height
Worksheets("EDR").ButtonType.Left = Worksheets("EDR").Range(cell).Left
Worksheets("EDR").ButtonType.Top = Worksheets("EDR").Range(cell).Top
Worksheets("EDR").ButtonType.Width = Worksheets("EDR").Range(cell).Width
```

However, I have been unable to get the Worksheets command to function properly in this way.  I get an "Object doesn't support this property or method" error.

How can I reformat/reassign my ButtonType variable to be something that the Worksheets command will accept?

I have tried the formatting above and several other methods of referring to the "ButtonType" variable without success so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the command button using `Worksheet.OLEObjects`:

```
Select Case ButtonType
   Case "cmdJSON" 
       cell = "N13:O13"
   Case "cmdGraph"
       cell = "Z19:AA19"
   Case "cmdCopyCO2" 
       cell = "AH15"
End Select

With Worksheets("EDR").OLEObjects(ButtonType)
    .Object.AutoSize = False ' any reason for this step?
    .Object.AutoSize = True
    .Height = Worksheets("EDR").Range(cell).Height
    .Left = Worksheets("EDR").Range(cell).Left
    .Top = Worksheets("EDR").Range(cell).Top
    .Width = Worksheets("EDR").Range(cell).Width
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

### Place and Size Command Buttons

[image]

**Usage (Example)**

```vb
Sub PlaceButtonTEST()
    
    Dim BTypes(): BTypes = Array("cmdJSON", "cmdNOT", "cmdGraph", "cmdCopyCO2")
    
    Dim BType
    
    For Each BType In BTypes
        PlaceButton BType
    Next BType

End Sub
```

**The Method**

```vb
Sub PlaceButton(ByVal ButtonType As String)

    Dim BTypes(): BTypes = VBA.Array("cmdJSON", "cmdGraph", "cmdCopyCO2")
    Dim Addresses(): Addresses = VBA.Array("N13:O13", "Z19:AA19", "AH15")
    Dim HeightMultipliers(): HeightMultipliers = VBA.Array(1.5, 1.5, 1)
    Dim HeightDivisors(): HeightDivisors = VBA.Array(4, 4, 0)
    
    Dim Index: Index = Application.Match(ButtonType, BTypes, 0)
    
    If IsError(Index) Then Exit Sub
    
    Index = Index - 1
    
    Dim rg As Range, Buttons()
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("EDR")
         Set rg = .Range(Addresses(Index))
         Buttons = VBA.Array(.cmdJSON, .cmdGraph, .cmdCopyCO2)
    End With
    
    With Buttons(Index)
        .AutoSize = False
        .AutoSize = True
        .Height = rg.Height * HeightMultipliers(Index)
        .Left = rg.Left
        Dim CellTop As Double: CellTop = rg.Top
        If HeightDivisors(Index) > 0 Then
            CellTop = CellTop + rg.Height / HeightDivisors(Index)
        End If
        .Top = CellTop
        .Width = rg.Width
    End With

End Sub
```